# Hibernate - delete objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

If i want to remove an entity with hibernate i get the message `Removing a detached instance...`. I understand that's because my transaction/session is closed.

Currently how i do it: If i lookup an object, i open a transaction, do the lookup, commit, close the transaction. The same for the deletion.
Whats the right way to do the deletion? Do i need to keep my transaction open all the time (deletion is executed some time later as the lookup). Or do i need a lookup again for the deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Keep the session open longer so the same session that loaded the object can delete it - this really depends on the architecture of your application.

Alternative re-load the object just before your delete call.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create and execute a `DELETE` query with a `WHERE` clause passing the values of the primary key fields. In that case, you don't have to re-attach your entity.

Comment: Do i lose any hibernate functionality if if do the deletion "by hand". E.g. the "cascade" annotation -> Do children get deleted if i do it with a query?

Comment: Cascading is not working in that case, you'd have to control it manually.

Comment: @eternay: Cascading delete can also be specified at the DDL level.

Comment: Of course, but we were talking about "hibernate functionality".